VSTO Outlook: Using IOlkAccountManager to manage accounts operations
I have tried to detect accounts addition from Outlook without success. Here it is my previous post.
I have heard something about the interface IOlkAccountManager so I have tried to implement it but it is not working. Below my code snippet:
ThisAddin Class:
private IOlkAccountManager accountManager; // also tried defining it as dynamic
private uint adviseCookie;

[ComImport, Guid("000630C3-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IOlkAccountManager
{
    void Advise([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IAccountNotify pNotify, out uint pdwCookie);
    void Unadvise(uint dwCookie);
}

[ComImport, Guid("000630C4-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IAccountNotify
{
    void NotifyAccountChange();
}

private class AccountNotify : IAccountNotify
{
    public void NotifyAccountChange()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("A new account has been added or an account has been removed.");
    }
}

ThisAddin_Startup method:
object mapiObject = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
if (mapiObject!=null)
{
    accountManager=mapiObject as IOlkAccountManager;
    if (accountManager!=null)
    {
       accountManager.Advise(new AccountNotify(), out adviseCookie);
    }
}

When performing casting below i get null as result:
accountManager=mapiObject as IOlkAccountManager;

So what am i doing wrong?

Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT returns IMAPISession MAPI interface, not IOlkAccountManager. OOM does not provide access to IOlkAccountManager. You can access IOlkAccount interface from Account.IOlkAccount property, but that won't help you.
You can access the functionality provided by IOlkAccountManager through Redemption (I am its author) - its RDOAccounts object fires AccountAdd event not only for the new stores (since you are after StoreAdd event), but all Outlook accounts - PST, POP3, IMAP4, LDAP, etc.
